# Как создать объект на удаленной машине в нужном процессе

Tags: c++, windows, com

Имеется изолированная полностью контролируемая локальная сеть с машинами, вопросы безопасности не имеют значения. Еще есть несколько комовских DLL с реализациями и заместителями/заглушками для интерфейсов (proxy/stub). Необходимо создавать экземпляры этих реализаций на удаленных машинах в разных процессах. То есть должна быть возможность поднимать несколько отдельных процессов на одной машине с этими объектами. Причем иногда процессы нужны консольные, а иногда оконные, ну или пусть всегда будут оконные. Экземпляров одной реализации в процессе так же может быть по несколько штук. Предполагается что учет всех объектов ведет одна из машин.

Так вот вопрос, как реализовать это средствами DCOM?

Непонятно вот что. Процесс при старте должен вызывать для каждой фабрики функцию [CoRegisterClassObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693407(v=vs.85).aspx) с ней нужно передать CLSID реализации, указатель на фабрику и флажки с параметрами активации. Это понятно, допустим процесс знает список реализаций и спокойно их регистрирует. Но на клиентской стороне я должен вызвать [CoCreateInstanceEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680701(v=vs.85).aspx) и передать с ней имя машины, CLSID реализации и все. Больше ничего нет чтобы идентифицировать процесс. Как быть, свой механиз воротить?

Смежный вопрос. Если я одновременно зарегистрирую реализации из DLL и из процессов, как DCOM их отличит? Регистрация DLL нужна чтобы их можно было активировать локально из процессов. Как вариант конечно, DLL можно не регистрировать, а подгружать вручную.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то есть одна главная машина которая регистрирует другие агент-машины/процессы. Регистрируй каждого агента на сервере. И оставляй там данные: нетворк-Имя машины, порт выделенный под процесс агента, название процесса, айдишник (если одна апликуха там может быть запущена несколько раз) и еще какую-либо инфу.

Так ты сможешь проверить кто вообще онлайн из агентов/апликух. И не важно агент это консольная апликуха или оконная. Этим же сервером можешь проверять доступность машин каждые там 30 секунд :)

Если нужна информация что бы послать запрос на нужную машину/процесс -- просто делаешь запрос на сервер и он тебе отвечает нужной информацией.

Как я написал выше -- открывай порт на каждом из агентов. Если на этот порт приходят какие-то специфические данные -- это должно вызывать ивент в котором и создается нужный тебе обьект. Если какие-то другие специфические данных приходят на порт -- создавай совсем другой обьект своей фабрикой :)

Пример специфичных данных которые должны прийти: `типОбьектаКоторыйНужноСоздать, ИмяМашиныКотораяСделалаЗапросНаСоздание, Какие-либоПараметры создания` и все в строке. Если нужно посылай -- сериализованный набор битов который нужно десериализовать, если данные пришли... На твой вкус :) По-факту разницы никакой.

Прости если что не написал, т.к. многие вопросы из заданных я не понял, как-то все очень сумбурно написано :) Но основной вопрос решится именно таким вот макаром.

Comment: Задача в том, чтобы все это делать готовыми средствами DCOM, а не писать свое. То есть я хочу прозрачно работать с объектами и интерфейсами, а не с портами и запросами/пакетами. Какие вопросы не понятны?

Comment: Ну готовой реализации я точно не встречал, т.к. сам вообще пишу на другом языке :) Но все равно желаю удачных поисков "коробочного" решения задачи :)

Answer (score 0):

Ответ (или точнее путь) есть в англоязычном SO [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867988/remote-com-server-instantiation).
Создаете [COM+ application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687759(VS.85).aspx), затем [инсталлятор](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680546(VS.85).aspx), и потом [прокси](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679498(VS.85).aspx) на клиентах поднимаете.